# MacBook Pro 13" 2016 - How to set up dual monitors?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, hdmi

I own the MacBook Pro 13" 2016 model. It has two thunderport 3 ports on the left side of itself.

I have two Samsung monitors with a HDMI IN on both monitors.

Do I need to buy two Thunderbold 3 to HDMI adapters, to connect both my monitors?

I just tried connecting them with a HDMI Splitter, but it only shows the same content on both monitors. I just found out, that a single HDMI cable can only show content for one monitor or split the same content to two monitors. So that just failed hard.

But the only option is to then have two adapter connected at the same time, to get use of both my monitors...?

EDIT: I've tried to search for similar answers but could not find anything. Also I have a HDMI splitter, which just simply displays the same content on both monitors, so that was little to none help.

I've got on Thunderbolt to HDMI, 2x USB and another Thunderbolt port.

Best solution would be a adapter with one Thunderbolt port but with two HDMI ports.

Comment: There's dozens of questions and answers here about that topic.  Have you searched for them?  If so, what part(s) of the answer's presented have you tried and what doesn't work for you?

Comment: I have, and could not find any answer to my question. Sadly!

Comment: Right now I have an HDMI 1x2 Splitter. That just outputs the exact same content on both screen. I have a Thunderbolt 3 adapter to HDMI (and two USB ports + one more Thunderbolt / USB-C). Perfect solution would be one Thunderbolt 3 adapter with two HDMI ports I assume... If that exist and works.

Comment: Please edit your question to indicate that you've performed a search for similar questions and couldn't locate an answer.  Also add the comment above so that all relevant info is contained in the question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a single cable solution, have a look at the [CalDigit Thunderbolt Station](http://radnex.us/caldigit_TB_Station).

You will need to go from DisplayPort to HDMI and then Thunderbolt/USBC to HDMI (another adapter), but you will be able to connect two HDMI monitors ultimately from one (Thunderbolt) USB-C cable from your Mac.

[image]

Now, if your Samsung monitor supports Display Port, I would use that interface instead of going to HDMI.  So, I would use a Display Port to Display Port cable and a USB-C to Display Port adapter (instead of HDMI).

There's a really good review of it on [YouTube](https://youtu.be/0Pqp8Tz_eEQ)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to use a USB-C/Thunderbolt3 to HDMI adapter.

macOS will update the display output as you connect them to your MacBook Pro.

Comment: There's no more elegant way than having two adapters connected at the same time? There's not a Thunderbolt to HDMI x2 adapter out there for example?

Comment: @NewMacBookProOwner you can use a thunderbolt dock instead with a) 1 HDMI and 1 thunderbolt output or b) with two HDMI outputs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think I've got a better picture of the situation. Seems like I just will end up buying one more adapter. The docks seem to be quite expensive compared to the adapters.

Comment: @NewMacBookProOwner yes it's a more elegant solution but also quite a bit more expensive. You may also connect one of your display to an AppleTV and connect to it wirelessly. Again, this is a expensive solution as well.